# Is there anyway to extract files from an s3 bucket using ls and wildcards? (aws cli)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, aws-cli

I have a couple of issues trying to list matching files within a directory in my s3 bucket.

I have been using an ls to create a list of all my files within a specific directory (including timestamps and file sizes) by appending this to a new file, for example `aws s3 --profile mybucket1 ls s3://my-bucket1/directory1/directory2/ >> list.txt`.

This is working both quickly and as intended. However, I also have some files within directory1 that I want to list too, but only certain files that match a specific string with wildcards around it.

The closest I have got to achieving this is using cp (with --exclude and --include) instead of an ls, because ls does not allow you to use the --exclude or --include options, for example `aws s3 --profile mybucket1 cp s3://my-bucket1/directory1/ /path/to/local/directory/ --exclude "*" --include "*match-me*" --recursive` but it is taking forever to even copy a single file across (I don't get any stdout as I believe it scans the whole directory looking for the matching string before it copies anything). I'm also unable to remove --recursive as it gives me an error without it, even though I only want to copy files within directory1.

My preference would be to use an ls for this as it's much faster and I don't have to then do another ls on the downloaded files to produce the same format as the files I listed and appended from directory2.

Also, I am running all these commands within a bash script, in case that makes any difference.

I hope this makes sense and if anybody has any possible solutions to this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: check out "aws s3 sync help"

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, follow the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing-aws-azure-google-openstack-etc?referrer=Gtut7wQSWPk88jFJz_zqMg2) and up-vote some sample questions.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [`aws s3api list-objects`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects.html)

1. If your pattern is at the start of the key and you want to match against `match-me*`, you can use the `--prefix` arguments :

   ```
   aws s3api list-objects --bucket <bucket> --prefix "match-me"
   ```

   will return all keys starting with *match-me*
2. If your pattern is at the middle of key name and you want to match against `*match-me*`, you can run a query against the results:

   ```
   aws s3api list-objects --bucket test-bucket-fh --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'match-me')]"
   ```

Comment: also note that list-objects only returns up to 1000 objects.

Comment: @LHWizard correct, this needs pagination if you have more than 1000 objects in your bucket

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I ran this command but it's taking ages to give any output. I'm assuming this is because it's scanning the entire bucket with the query. I'll see how long it takes to run but I would prefer something similar to what I wrote in my question as that is a very quick process because it's not going through the entire bucket.

Comment: so you better off running the same command listing all files and finding the match locally `aws s3 --profile mybucket1 ls s3://my-bucket1/directory1/ --recusive | grep "match-me" > list.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If your need to list the contents of Amazon S3 is not urgent (eg do it once per day), then you can use [Amazon S3 Storage Inventory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html):

> **Amazon S3 inventory** provides a comma-separated values (CSV) flat-file output of your objects and their corresponding metadata on a **daily or weekly basis** for an S3 bucket or a shared prefix (that is, objects that have names that begin with a common string).

It provides a daily/weekly file in Amazon S3 containing a list of all objects. Additional [charges](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) apply.

Comment: Can you filter on object extensions (*.png) when creating an inventory?

Comment: @Ivthillo Amazon S3 inventory provides a complete listing of the objects in a bucket. You can then process that data however you wish. It is often used by people who have **millions** of objects in an S3 bucket.